# if $w[n]$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$ are uncorrelated for all $n$, then are $x[n]=A+w[n]$ uncorrelated?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation

Suppose $w[n]$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$ are uncorrelated for all $n$ integers.

Define $x[n]=A+w[n]$ for all $n$ where $A \ne0$ real number.

Then are all the $x[n]$'s uncorrelated (i.e. are $x[0]$ and $x[1]$ uncorrelated?  How about $x[1]$ and $x[2]$)?

Here is my thinking:

Since $w[n]$ are uncorrelated for all n, this means $E[w[i]w[j]]=0$ for all $i \ne j$.

So $E[x[i]x[j]]=E[(A+w[i])(A+w[j])]=E[A^2+Aw[j]+Aw[i]+w[i]w[j]]$

$=E[A^2]+AE[w[j]]+AE[w[i]] + E[w[i]w[j]]$

$=A^2+0+0+0$

$=A^2$

Since $E[x[i][x[j]]=A^2 \ne 0$, then the $x[i]$ and $x[j]$ are not uncorrelated for $i \ne j $.  Correct?

Comment: Keep in mind $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) -E(X)E(Y)$  You are forgetting the $E(X)E(Y)$ part.

Comment: Good thinking! If you are thinking of the $\{x[n]\}$ as comprising a time series (also called a discrete-time random process), then the _autocorrelation function_ of this time series is defined as $R_x(n,m) = E[x[n],x[m]]$ and it has value $A^2$ for $n\neq m$ and value $\sigma^2+A^2$ when $n=m$. If you are thinking of the $x[n]$'s as individual random variables, then your formula for their _correlation_ is all wrong. _Correlation_ or _correlation coefficient_ has a specific meaning and what you have is not it.